# Ember input helper placeholder not working for password and email type

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js

I am trying to create sign up and log in forms for my Ember app.  I am using the input helpers, but when I set the field for email and password the placeholder text comes in the format of the respective types and also shows the "value" as the placeholder text instead of the defined "placeholder" text.  The first name and last name fields show the correct placeholder text and in the correct format.
Here is the code from my sign up template:

```
{{input type="text" value=firstname id="firstname" placeholder="first name" autofocus="autofocus"}}
    {{input type="text" value=lastName placeholder="last name"}}
    {{input type="email" placeholder="email" value="emailAddress"}}
    {{input type="password" placeholder="password" value="password"}}
    {{input type="password" placeholder="confirm password" value="confirmPassword"}}
```

Here is what the form looks like as a result:
[image: form]

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because the value  passing to the input helper in case of password is a string

```
{{input type="password" placeholder="password" value="password"}}
```

it should be

```
{{input type="password" placeholder="password" value=password}}
```

[see this Twiddle](https://ember-twiddle.com/70c6aecac59e17de8c55207694f0fb51?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2C)